# Angular: canactivate auth gaurd issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am learning angular 13 & i am stuck at point, below is the code

this is my authservice file

```
export class AuthService {
  loggedIn = false;

  isAuthenticated() {
    const promise = new Promise(
      (resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(this.loggedIn);
        }, 800);
      }
    );
    return promise;
  }
}
```

i am getting this error

this is my auth guard service file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  CanActivate,
  Router,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated()
      .then(
        (authenticated: boolean) => {
          if (authenticated) {
            return true;
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
          }
        }
      );
    }
}
```

screenshot of error
[image]

**Can anybody help me??**

Comment: After this.router.navigate(['/']); add return false;

Comment: @MikeOne thnx.. its working now!.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `return false` in your `else` statement.

```
.
.
.
if (authenticated) {
    return true;
} else {
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
    return false; // <- add this here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue occured because there is no return in your 'else' part.
Try the Below code.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
return this.authService.isAuthenticated()
  .then(
    (authenticated: boolean) => {
      if (authenticated) {
        return true;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
        return false;
      }
    }
  );
}
```